# Google Maps InfoBox Not Displaying Correctly in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps

I can only post one link so here is a reference page with corresponding links:

I am using a modified version of extinfowindow for Google Maps v3 (reference link 1)
to display a custom infobox window for my markers. While I
successfully implemented the InfoBox in v3, I ran into an issue with
IE during testing. The infobox renders correctly in all browsers but
IE. However, if I view the infobox HTML directly with IE, it renders
correctly. But, when I view the infobox within the map (click on a
marker), I see this: (reference link 2). The HTML file is
at (reference link 3) and should render fine in any
browser when viewed directly. The infobox javascript I am using is at
(reference link 4).

I am not sure why the display only messes up when rendered on the map
in IE. I have changed the positioning and class/id to check for any
conflicts but have had no luck. The positioning and backgrounds get
messed up in IE no matter what I change. I am missing something?
Please let me know if I need to give any extra information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use inline CSS for the info window. When rendering the info window HTML itself, IE processed the CSS correctly. However, when rendering the info window HTML on the map canvas, IE would ignore the  tags and would only render inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

MSIE often needs the correct DOCTYPE to display things with precise alignments.

Try using

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: The problem seems to be rendering the view within Google Maps itself. IE renders it fine when viewed by itself. See the links on the reference page for an example.